# Snowflake python connector - apache mod_wgsi response issue

Tags: python, apache, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, mod-wsgi

From my web UI, Snowflake sql queries through apache & mod_wsgi does not return the results, webpage just hangs. However queries from other databases return results to the front end, only snowflake queries doesn’t work.
The same snowflake sql queries return results through development local server (werkzeug)

It seems like a snowflake python driver interaction with Apache seem to be the problem, considering other databases works just fine. Please let us know if you need any additional info. Thank you for your attention

Environment:
AWS EC2 – Amazon Linux 2 - centos rhel fedora
Apache: 2.4.46
mod-wsgi  4.7.1 (Production WSGI server)
Python: 3.7.9
Werkzeug  1.0.1 (development wgsi server with Flask)
snowflake-connector-python 2.3.10 (also tried 2.3.7)

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Please see the following for a good idea of how to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't code related. Just the snowflake python connector and  the issue working with mod_wsgi. Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to debug or give advice if there's no code, logs, or any way to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question. Just wanted to let you know that I've faced the same issue: snowflake request just hangs w/o any error or warning (and eventually stops after pretty big timeout I've set to avoid it from hanging forever). My configuration is pretty same as mentioned above; also I tried it on several ubuntu instances, nothing works.

But I was able to make it work on Google Cloud instance; the other issue is that huge requests fail on google cloud with "Exceeded hard memory limit" error; no wonder as it's free tier. But sad moment is that our management decided to pay for ec2 instance, not for google cloud non-free instance. So my custom Flask/Python APi can't return huge csv result file and I think about zipping it as a workaround (if we still continue using free tier there).

Can't really say what they use instead of mod_wsgi on google cloud, but it does work. Just my guess, it's nginx + uWSGI. Related reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/16tm4e/what_wsgi_servers_you_use/

So my suggestion is to (1) try it on Google Cloud instance instead. Or try to (2) install nginx + uWSGI instead of apache + mod_wgsi. As I can't have paid Google Cloud instance on prod, I'm about to try nginx + uWSGI myself.

Also I agree with topic starter that it is not code related at all.
Though I also agree with above Simon Darr's and Felipe Hoffa's comments: Snowflake guys need some code to reproduce anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I have talked to Snowflake support team and they confirmed it is the compatibility issue with the python connector and mod_wsgi - he says from the debug logs the last statement executed is   "Query result format: arrow", hence the assumption is that snowflake returned the results, which was also confirmed by snowflake query logs.